# SQL WHERE Clause Condition Not working

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table:

```
City1      City2

London     New York
New York   London
Mumbai     London
New York   Mumbai
```

This is, what i want:

If someone select: London + New York, then all the rows, which contain both London+New York will get displayed. No matter, what comes first.

I want this to display, if someone select: London & New York

```
London     New York
New York   London
```

This is my current code:

```
WHERE City1='London' AND City2='New York';\
```

It only display this:

```
London     New York
```

Comment: Are you looking to use `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: I want both city's, so `AND`.

Comment: You might take a look at LEAST and GREATEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WHERE IN()`:

```
WHERE City1 IN ('London','New York') AND City2 IN ('London','New York');
```

If you like to don't select row if are same, you can try this:

```
WHERE City1 IN ('London','New York') AND City2 IN ('London','New York') and City1 != City2
```

Comment: This isn't right, it would return true for rows where both cities are London.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
WHERE (City1='London' AND City2='New York') or (City1='New York' AND City2='London')
```

it is not the best solution but it might work;)

Comment: I think this is the best solution +1

Comment: This one requires an astute use of parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for two comparisons...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE LEAST(col1,col2) = LEAST('val1','val2') 
   AND GREATEST(col1,col2) = GREATEST('va1l','val2');
```